# Alternating paths in Niagara

Tags: niagara

[Niagara](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/13308/niagara) (sometimes called Iguazu) has one of the most entertaining boards I've ever encountered. It's a shame that sometimes a river piece gets stuck, or two consecutive river pieces move down the same side of the waterfall instead of alternating.

When the latter occurs, are we supposed to 'fix' it (e.g. pieces are supposed to alternate) or not (pieces go where they happen to go when you push)?

We always went with alternating pieces, but sometimes it can be difficult to establish which way the last piece went to determine the direction of the next one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules state - "players should push the disc by hand in the opposite direction of the direction the previous disc moved".

It shouldn't be to hard to know which way it previously went as it only happened a moment ago.  Also the rules do state that the river is "usually alternating, but not always".  If a group really can't remember which way the river just went then just randomly decide the next direction.

I find if a player gently holds the board down either side of where the board fold is and the river splits that prevents the river discs from getting jammed.

I use the fact the discs fall at the bottom of the river and leave a leave a disc there as a reminder which fell last. there are 3 spare discs so one pile always has 2 and the other always has one meaning the river should fall there next.